# Julia: counting total number of elements in an array-of-arrays

Tags: arrays, julia, jagged-arrays, arrayofarrays

Is there a single function in Julia that will give you the total number of elements in an array-of-arrays (or 'jagged array')?

Here's what I mean:

```
my_array_of_arrays = [ [1, 5], [6], [10, 10, 11] ]
```

I'm looking for a function such that
`desired_function(my_array_of_arrays)` will return `6`

And if not, what's the quickest way to do this in Julia?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it without additional dependencies would be to use [`sum`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.sum):

```
julia> my_array_of_arrays = [ [1, 5], [6], [10, 10, 11] ] 
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 5]
 [6]
 [10, 10, 11]

julia> sum(length, my_array_of_arrays)
6
```

However, if you want to work more intensively with ragged arrays, you might be better off using specialized packages, such as [`ArraysOfArrays.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/ArraysOfArrays.jl).

Comment: More succinct is `sum(length, x)`.

Comment: @MattB. Thanks, I edited my answer to reflect your comment

Answer (score 4):

`sum(length, x)` suggested by @MattB is a more elegant answer and it deserves being here so others can find it.

Testing:

```
julia> my_array_of_arrays = [ [1, 5], [6], [10, 10, 11] ]
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 5]
 [6]
 [10, 10, 11]

julia> sum(length, my_array_of_arrays)
6
```

Note that the performance of both methods `mapreduce(length, +, x)` and `sum(length, x)` is identical since both do not materialize the data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I see that the original poster of the 'accepted answer' has edited their answer to reflect this.